# Dukt Analytics Plugin - Web Profile not showing up

Tags: plugins, analytics

I'm trying to configure the Dukt Analytics Plugin to a site for my first time. I was able to successfully configure oAuth on my Google account, and get the account connected via the Analytics Plugin panel in Craft.

However, I'm having some issues getting the web profile dropdown list to populate. While connecting to Google Analytics, the only permissions it asked for was "have offline access" which may be part of the issue.

Is there any sort of troubleshooting methods that can be done to figure out why no web profiles are showing up?

Comment: I don't know much about that plugin, but it sounds like it might be a bug. Have you tried contacting the developer directly?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried contacting the developer directly about five days ago without any response as of yet. If I do hear anything back, or am able to figure anything out, I'll be sure to share.

Comment: Sounds good, please do share your findings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the latest Craft Update, the plugin seems to be working fine now. It was either a bug in Craft that has been fixed, or you just have to give Google a few days before it's able to fetch the list of hosted analytics accounts.